# Implementando Classe AudioTrack no modo static

Tags: android

Estou tentando fazer em app bem simples para eu aprender a implementar a classe AudioTrack  (`android.media.AudioTrack`).
O app é apenas uma tela com um botão, que quando pressionado deve reproduzir um arquivo .wav de 1seg. O app instala sem problemas no emulador, mas quando clico no botão para tocar o som, ele dá erro.
A minha implementação da `audioTrack` está correta?

```java
//MainActivity

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private DrumKit dk = new DrumKit();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        }  

    public void onClick(View v) { 
        dk.playAudio();
    } 

}

//Classe para executar o audio:

public class DrumKit {

     byte[] byteData = null;
     private File file = null; 
     private AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100,
            AudioFormat. CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 88200,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC );

     public void playAudio(){

         file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "snare.wav");
         byteData = new byte[(int) file.length()];

         audioTrack.play();
         audioTrack.write(byteData, 0, byteData.length); 
         audioTrack.stop();
         audioTrack.release();
     }
}
```

//Logcat:

```java
06-05 10:23:01.131: D/gralloc_goldfish(1381): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-05 10:23:14.371: D/AndroidRuntime(1381): Shutting down VM
06-05 10:23:14.371: W/dalvikvm(1381): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a1eba8)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381): Process: com.example.airdrums, PID: 1381
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at     android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     ... 11 more
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: play() called on uninitialized AudioTrack.
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.media.AudioTrack.play(AudioTrack.java:984)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at com.example.airdrums.DrumKit.playAudio(DrumKit.java:25)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at com.example.airdrums.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:51)
06-05 10:23:14.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: @AndreCSimoes, será que o fato de dar stop/release logo depois de dar play não causa problemas (mesmo sendo de 1 segundo)? Não vale a pena testar

Comment: @Wakin eu já tentei comentar o stop e release, mas não deu certo!

Comment: O logcat indica que o AudioTrack não foi inicializado correctamente. Verifique qual é o ***state*** do AudioTrack através de: `audioTrack.getState();`. Mais info em [AudioStack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#getState%28%29)

Comment: Só uma pergunta... Você por acaso declarou as duas classes públicas no mesmo arquivo? Ou apenas colocou elas juntas aqui na sua pergunta? Um arquivo de código fonte não pode ter duas classes públicas.

Answer (score 1):

Na inicialização do seu `AudioTrack` tem um espaço em um argumento. Veja bem:

```
private AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100,
            AudioFormat. CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 88200,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC );
```

O argumento `AudioFormat. CHANNEL_OUT_MONO` está com um espaço depois do ponto, remova este espaço. Outra coisa que percebi é que na [documentação da classe `AudioTrack`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#play%28%29) referente ao método `play()`, diz o seguinte:

> Starts playing an AudioTrack. If track's creation mode is MODE_STATIC,
>   you must have called write() prior.

Traduzindo...

> Inicia a reprodução de um AudioTrack. Se o modo de criação da faixa é
>   **MODE_STATIC**, você deve chamar write() antes.

Como seu modo de criação da faixa aí é `MODE_STATIC`, então inverta as linhas:

```
audioTrack.play();
audioTrack.write(byteData, 0, byteData.length);
```

O método write tem que ser chamado antes do `play()`. Veja se isso resolve.